# What's a good writer community that mostly discusses self-publishing?

Tags: self-publishing, community

I'm apart of a lot of strong and well read writer communities that mostly discuss traditional means of publishing. However, I want to broaden my knowledge on the nature of self-publishing. Are there any writers' communities that deal specifically with self-publishing? I'm interested in both avenues, and I'm trying to find a balance of information.

Comment: Why don’t you ask your questions here?

Comment: Self-publishing is on-topic here, but I also believe this question should get some good feedback from our members who are involved in self-publishing mailing lists and forums.

Comment: @John - There are some questions it's hard to ask on SE sites.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest that you check out the [Kindleboards](http://www.kindleboards.com) community. They are very receptive, highly supportive, and willing to respond to any kind of question, regardless of how it is worded. You may find a lot of cheering going on as well, but then it is more about community and less about just asking questions.

Another suggestion, if you happen to have a Facebook account, is to look up the Indie Writers Unite group. They are also very receptive to all kinds of questions, and they are also quick to offer suggestions and advice based on their own experiences with self-publishing.

Both places are full of people who can and will help in anyway possible to answer questions, regardless of the platform on which you choose to publish. There are folks there who can help you with everything from formatting, book covers, promotion, and advertising. They will also help you tweet your new releases and use their own social media channels to help promote other members. Also, the IWU group has an ongoing blog tour for members who want to participate.

Both communities have over 500 active members who are very engaging and very supportive.

Comment: Thank you Steven for your suggestions. I have been to a lot of forums with self-pub. discussions, and many of the members are so timorous about discussing the wide range of opportunity out of a fear of seeming naive about the possibility of success. Again, thank you. I'm not sure I can thank you enough.